# Is there an easy way to invert boolean values in xslt

Tags: xpath

I want to make 0 => 1 and 1 => 0, is there a simple way to do this in xslt?

Comment: There are many ways, but context would make the difference. Also, what it's the "simple" criteria?

Comment: This is actually an XPath question.

Comment: Good question, +1. Besides @Alejandro 's excellent example, see my answer for other simple and short expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $value is an instance of or castable as a number data type, this would be the most simple expression:

```
1 - $value
```

Answer (score 2):

The "not" function?

http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_not.html

although if you actually want the number you will need to use the "number" function

Comment: This `number(not($value))` would be `number(not(boolean($value)))`: three function calls. One could ask what it means the simple criteria.

Comment: fair point, I think this all rides on whether the required input and output are actually boolean or numbers

Answer (score 2):

**There are many expressions that take `0` or `1` and evaluate, respectively, to `1` or `0`.**:

@Alejandro already pointed out one of the simplest such expressions, here are others:

```
$a + $b - $v
```

**This is a generalisation of @Alejandro's formula** (`1 - $v`) and transforms `$a` to `$b` and `$b` to `$a` for any two numbers `$a` and `$b`

```
$v = 0
```

Formally one needs to write this as: `number($v = 0)` but in XPath 1.0 if this expression is used in other expressions, where a number is expected, the conversion is done automatically (behind the scene).

**and also**:

```
$v + 1 mod 2
```

**and even**:

```
substring('01',$v+1)
```

**In XPath 2.0 there is a natural language support for such expressions**:

```
if($v eq $a)
   then $b
   else $a
```

or the much shorter:

```
($a,$b)[not(. eq $v)]
```

**Finally**, this is the equivalent XPath 2.0 expression for *nodes* `$a` and `$b`:

```
($a,$b) except $v
```